# removeFromSuperview then paste new view, it won't release memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I found PDFView will cause memory leak, so I try another way to show PDF.

I use a scrollView that has a contentView for all the PDF page size.

[image]

For example, if one PDF page resolution is 480 x 320, then 5 pages PDF's contentView size is 2400 x 320. And I reuse 3 UIViews (as above image, preload and current pages) for showing PDF pages on contentView, every page size is 480 x 320. If now it shows 1st page, then preload 2nd page; if it shows 2nd page, then preload 1st page and 3rd page.

[image]

When scrollview moves to next page, I always load the current shown page and next/last page. So I have to remove page using removeFromSuperview(). Then I load the removed page as new one, and paste it into new position on contentView.

The problem is, removing the page from superview won't release the memory. So a many pages PDF will crash when memory is overload.

So how could I force release memory? I have read those old posts but not find the answer.

Comment: Just `removeFromSuperview()` is not enough if your UIView has strong reference to something else from its superview.

Comment: I think you should used `UIPageViewController `. It will automatically handle the reuse process. 
For the memory I agree with @Starsky. A strong reference may block the memory release. To understand how to avoid memory leaks `ARC` you should read this : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: @Arthur I use UIScrollView with UICollectionView before. It has no memory issue, but there is problem when zooming in and scroll. I think UIPageViewController is similar with UIPageViewController?